# Open a link in new tab/window without loosing the view scope of current JSF page

Tags: jsf, navigation, view-scope, new-window

I need to open a new JSF page (say `2.xhtml`) in new tab from current JSF page (say `1.xhtml`).
Which JSF component should I use for it? `<h:commandLink>` or `<h:outputLink>`?

I do not want to lose the scope of current page `1.xhtml` after clicking on the link to open `2.xhtml` in new tab.

The bean of `1.xhtml` is `@ViewScoped`. Should I change it to `@RequestScoped`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML, a link which opens the given URL in a new window/tab via a GET request is to be achieved using `<a ... target="_blank">`.

In JSF you can just write down plain vanilla HTML:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/2.xhtml" target="_blank">Open 2.xhtml in new window</a>
```

You can also use `<h:outputLink>`, which is only beneficial if you ever want to use its `rendered` attribute:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/2.xhtml" target="_blank">Open 2.xhtml in new window</h:outputLink>
```

You can also use `<h:link>` which can take a navigation outcome instead of an URL, JSF will then generate the right URL:

```
<h:link value="Open 2.xhtml in new window" outcome="2" target="_blank" />
```

The bean scope is irrelevant to this all. Just choose the right one for the data it holds. The `<h:commandLink>` is insuitable as it fires a POST request instead of a GET request.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)